# Component event vs aura:method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

When we have `aura:method` to make call from parent to child, child to parent component with arguments, why do we need `component event`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cmp_methods.htm) says:

> Use aura:method to communicate down the containment hierarchy. For
> example, a parent component calls an aura:method on a child component
> that it contains.
>
> To communicate up the containment hierarchy, fire a component event in
> the child component and handle it in the parent component.

Using aura:method to communicate to the parent means that multiple listeners are not possible (adding a new listener would "bump" the old listener off without warning). Using aura:method to communicate downwards means that the parent must notify the child of changes, as opposed to using an aura:valueChange event, which means the parent can simply set an attribute and as many child components as necessary are notified automatically.

In other words, it causes undue complications that could be avoided by using component or application events. That's not to say you *can't* use aura:method, but you should consider it a last resort after using events. The only time when aura:method is really useful is when the child component wants to return a value. Service components are an example of this design. While relatively rare, there are times when aura:method is appropriate. However, you should get used to using components as the preferred method of communication.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link and the explanation, that make sense.  Cheers!